# How to convert string date to moment?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, momentjs

i have an array i.e.

```
var a = [{startRealTime:Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Thu May 17 2018 11:25:01 GMT+0530 (IST), …},startTime:685}]
```

i deep copy array of object by method JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)).
so it's gives me

```
var a = [startRealTime:"2018-05-17T05:55:01.149Z",startTime:685]
```

which causing error in my datepicker how to convert it back to old, or if there is an another way of deep copying array of object without parse and stringify.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i did it by using for (var i = 0; i < slot.length; i++) {
         slot[i].startRealTime = moment(this.state.slots[i].startRealTime);
       }

Comment: but any better solution is most welcome

Comment: explain little bit more... and which datepicker you are using?

Comment: any date picker you use when you select date it generate Moment object.
but when i clone this array in which Moment object is store, Moment Object changed to "2018-05-17T05:55:01.149Z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the moment again to convert it again

```
var a = [startRealTime:moment("2018-05-17T05:55:01.149Z"),startTime:685]
```